# 3d Printing Problems

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, 3d-printing

I have some problems when I try to 3d print my project, so I'll be as specific as possible.

I first created this mask, and applied a solidify modifier to it:
[image]

The first time I exported as .stl, but it showed up blank in the 3d printing software, Cura. I then applied the solidify modifier, yet it still was blank when imported.

I then tried to export as .obj, which worked fine. I could see it in Cura. I began the 3d printing, using an ultimaker2, yet it did not seem to be working. It started the printing but ended up just moving the material around.

One thing to note is that when looking at the Layers in Cura, it seems that even with the solidify modifier, it looks infinitely thin, only showing some thickness. Why would this be? Could it be a problem with the export options, or with my mask itself?

Here is the project file if anyone could look at it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByCsi4JV6Yv1WXBfSkJlTnd1SUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you might be interested in the proposed [3d printing site of StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438/3d-printing)

Comment: It seems that you must have a certain amount of reputation on that site to ask a question, yet I need an answer quite soon. To the best of my knowledge this is a problem with me and Blender, as I am only a beginner and am most likely missing something quite simple.

Comment: If you really want to learn, upload a .blend file so some of us can have a look at it. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ .

Comment: Here is a link to the project file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByCsi4JV6Yv1WXBfSkJlTnd1SUU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The usual culprits for this sort of thing are as follows:

- Too small (scale) : most 3d slicing software has their units set up so that blender should export .stl's at .1 scale.  Otherwise, the object may be waaaay to big. or waaay too small. Try playing with the export scale and the object scale and see if you have any luck.

  - Too thin : the parallel problem to the scale issue is that if it is too thin, the object will not slice properly.  There is a minimum thickness the printer is capable of, and the slicer will exclude things that are too thin.
  - Inverted normals : if the normals are not set the right way, the slicer will not be able to detect the solidity of the object.
  - Non-Manifold :  Your object must be closed, or the slicer will not be able to detect the solidity of the object.

Due to your description, it sounds like one of the last three.

Answer (score 0):

One other option is to use a free 3rd party tool like the plugin from 3YOURMIND https://www.3yourmind.com/3d-print-add-on-blender so that you can see exactly where the errors are occurring when preparing the file for 3D printing with specific materials. You will be able to see if the file is simply too small, or if specific walls are two thin. The software will also do many of the basic repairs (fixing inverted walls, connecting edges, etc) for you.

Then you can download the file to do your printing, or use one of the connected 3D Print services to create the model for you. I find that especially being able to see where exactly the model has the thin walls to be a big time saver!